# Group by Object from Array Object to Tree Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, group-by, reduce, arrayobject

I need help group object like here:
Input array is:

```
[
    {
        Id: '1234',
        Name: 'Country - Viet Nam',
        AdminLevel: 2
    },
    {
        Id:'5678',
        Name: 'Province - Ho Chi Minh',
        AdminLevel: 4,
        ParentId: '1234'
    },
    {
        Id:'91011',
        Name: 'Province - Ha Noi',
        AdminLevel: 4,
        ParentId: '1234'
    },
    {
        Id:'111213',
        Name: 'Province - Da Nang',
        AdminLevel: 4,
        ParentId: '1234'
    },
    {
        Id:'111213',
        Name: 'District - Quan 1',
        AdminLevel: 6,
        ParentId: '5678'
    },
    {
        Id:'111213',
        Name: 'District - Quan 2',
        AdminLevel: 6,
        ParentId: '5678'
    },
    {
        Id:'111213',
        Name: 'District - Quan 3',
        AdminLevel: 6,
        ParentId: '5678'
    },
    {
        Id:'111213',
        Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 1',
        AdminLevel: 6,
        ParentId: '91011'
    },
    {
        Id:'111213',
        Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 2',
        AdminLevel: 6,
        ParentId: '91011'
    },
    {
        Id:'111213',
        Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 3',
        AdminLevel: 6,
        ParentId: '91011'
    }
    
]
```

And expect out-put is:

```
{
    Id: '1234',
    Name: 'Country - Viet Nam',
    AdminLevel: 2,
    Data: [
        {
            Id:'5678',
            Name: 'Province - Ho Chi Minh',
            AdminLevel: 4,
            ParentId: '1234',
            Data: [
                {
                    Id:'111213',
                    Name: 'District - Quan 1',
                    AdminLevel: 6,
                    ParentId: '5678'
                },
                {
                    Id:'111213',
                    Name: 'District - Quan 2',
                    AdminLevel: 6,
                    ParentId: '5678'
                },
                {
                    Id:'111213',
                    Name: 'District - Quan 3',
                    AdminLevel: 6,
                    ParentId: '5678'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            Id:'91011',
            Name: 'Province - Ha Noi',
            AdminLevel: 4,
            ParentId: '1234',
            Data: [
                {
                    Id:'111213',
                    Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 1',
                    AdminLevel: 6,
                    ParentId: '91011'
                },
                {
                    Id:'111213',
                    Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 2',
                    AdminLevel: 6,
                    ParentId: '91011'
                },
                {
                    Id:'111213',
                    Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 3',
                    AdminLevel: 6,
                    ParentId: '91011'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            Id:'111213',
            Name: 'Province - Da Nang',
            AdminLevel: 4,
            ParentId: '1234'
        },
    ]
}
```

Explain: We have to group by AdminLevel and then group by ParentId.

- Look away we have structure : Country(Parent) - Province(Multiple - Child of Country) - District (Multiple - Child of Province).
  Thanks you so much for helping me

Comment: So same parentId will have same `AdminLevel`. Your data structure seems so.

Comment: @Derek.W That might be coincidence. My guess is that they are matched based on  `ParentId` and `Id`.

Comment: If they have structure of `Country-Province-District...`, I think the items with same `ParentId` will have the same `Admin` level...

Comment: yeah, like that. ```ParentId``` in province , district is ```id``` of country , district

Comment: I have a quick question, why is the `Id` property not unique? Normally you expect an *id* to *identify* a resource. In your example data there are 7 objects with the same `Id` (111213).

Comment: Oof, the `Id` field isn't a unique identifier?  Half of those have the `Id` of `"111213"` which really messes up most straightforward ways of doing this.

Comment: Oh no, ```Id``` here is unique. Because it it ```ID``` of 1 country - 1 province - 1 districts follow GoogleMap, Sure that never duplicate here.

Comment: @phúphạm too bad, now you have answers that make arrays of things with the same `Id`, because the example data you gave has duplicate `Id`s.  Oops

Comment: sorry @jcalz I haven't checked data example carefully. sorry in here......but i still have thinking about the data is not ordered. i need sort it follow ```AdminLevel``` before using your algorithm?

Comment: The answers here don't care about `AdminLevel` because that's redundant information; both `ParentId` and `AdminLevel` encode something about where in the tree the entries should be, but `ParentId` tells you directly, while `AdminLevel` is, at best, a check.

Comment: okay thanks, i have solution in here :D thanks for help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is ordered so that parents come before children, it's fairly straight forward:

1. Go through all the nodes
2. For each find the parent
3. Add to the parent's `Data` property (or create it first if it's not there yet)
4. Return the root node

The root node would be the one that doesn't have any parents. You can use a map to keep track of the visited items and make it easier to lookup the parents.

Since your data doesn't have unique IDs, you need to keep an array of items for each ID. If your data happens to have a parent ID that matches two or more things, then each of them will have the child node.

```js
const data = [ { Id: '1234', Name: 'Country - Viet Nam', AdminLevel: 2 }, { Id:'5678', Name: 'Province - Ho Chi Minh', AdminLevel: 4, ParentId: '1234' }, { Id:'91011', Name: 'Province - Ha Noi', AdminLevel: 4, ParentId: '1234' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'Province - Da Nang', AdminLevel: 4, ParentId: '1234' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Quan 1', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '5678' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Quan 2', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '5678' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Quan 3', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '5678' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 1', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '91011' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 2', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '91011' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 3', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '91011' } ];

function group(arr) {
  let root;
  
  //keep a reference of all elements visited
  const lookup = new Map();
  
  //go through the array
  for (const item of arr) {
    //add to the lookup
    const key = item.Id;
    const value = lookup.get(key) ?? [];
    lookup.set(key, value.concat(item));
    
    if ("ParentId" in item){
      //find the parent(s) and update
      lookup.get(item.ParentId)
        .forEach(parent => {
          parent.Data = parent.Data ?? [];
          parent.Data.push(item);
        });
    } else {
      //if the item doesn't have a parent, it's the root node
      root = item;
    }
  }
  
  return root;
}

const result = group(data);

console.log(result);
```

If your data isn't ordered and parents might come before or after their children, the above code won't work, as it only visits and finds the parents in order, e.g., it will fail for  `[{Id: 2, ParentId: 1}, {Id: 1}]`. If that happens to be the case, you can change the body of the function to first index all items, and *then* add them to their respective parents:

```js
const data = [ { Id: '1234', Name: 'Country - Viet Nam', AdminLevel: 2 }, { Id:'5678', Name: 'Province - Ho Chi Minh', AdminLevel: 4, ParentId: '1234' }, { Id:'91011', Name: 'Province - Ha Noi', AdminLevel: 4, ParentId: '1234' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'Province - Da Nang', AdminLevel: 4, ParentId: '1234' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Quan 1', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '5678' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Quan 2', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '5678' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Quan 3', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '5678' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 1', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '91011' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 2', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '91011' }, { Id:'111213', Name: 'District - Tinh nao do Ha Noi 3', AdminLevel: 6, ParentId: '91011' } ];

function group(arr) {
  let root;
  
  //keep a reference of all elements visited
  const lookup = new Map();
  
  //first index all items
  for (const item of arr) {
     //add to the lookup
    const key = item.Id;
    const value = lookup.get(key) ?? [];
    lookup.set(key, value.concat(item));
  }
  
  //go through the array
  for (const item of arr) {
    if ("ParentId" in item){
      //find the parent(s) and update
      lookup.get(item.ParentId)
        .forEach(parent => {
          parent.Data = parent.Data ?? [];
          parent.Data.push(item);
        });
    } else {
      //if the item doesn't have a parent, it's the root node
      root = item;
    }
  }
  
  return root;
}

const result = group(data);

console.log(result);
```

This is still an `O(n)` solution, since it's going to be growing linearly with the input.

Note that this isn't grouping by `AdminLevel` as there doesn't seem a need to. The data naturally groups based on the `ParentId`. Grouping by `AdminLevel` first is an extraneous operation given that you do not expect multiple groups to exist for each parent.

See [a TypeScript solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgThCAeGAaKBhKEAewIB2AJgM5QAKcA9pHKANIQgB8UAvLFAGQUCGdAS14AbJACUIAYypwiSDOniIU6DMwDaAXWbMA3ACh9AMwCuBScAFUCUYFSUQxVKsBJJ9UT51z5iZCdKySACS6CTAcAIEAOasPOT8liLiUjJy5GERUbHM6B5ewdh4hKRQANZMVEawqPme5EW+pRUgVTV1mI0lZJQ0EHQgjCD6zAAU-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-qeF5XshvSalEkjQM+AAS2IYIcUAALJRPsuH5gBQEEKB4GQVA+5wUGCSukhW57oeME8U8v6rkQG4AJybgADJum5MUGX4EeuREkWRUDkbwUAnlQAhKYGLEgWBEHTNx4l8YOknITuB7riJS7iQJCk7puu6GfCKkbup5iaQAIjpZ4xJ5XjGWxpmcRZK5WQQbobnZwnwrBTkri5Cnbu5oWeN5yH+QIAIMk+UAAIomLwNiKaJ8LhexZlQGh1VeLF8XIeh2EOclokIUG6VuR5TU5fhG75YVFjFWVFVQNu2VQLVkXTI1llrHFAntThjnwj1gZ9ZlA3ibl66jVk43PpNNj7Su80cYtg18PxNmoZhG1daliGPa5e2zYdx2RKdsAMVABC8NiRDYtpun6VAVXidd9VLTFK2teuMnyYpm3wc5H0ZVld0-QVJ22s+MCA8DoPg0FUMzXdcOcQj+YtQJqMKZ1XgpVtWMJTjl35vjY1EwDBD7EDIMfBTkMCFAPNBrTt3LQ90lySzMH6JoBhTtY7y3sAc7sLY9ggk4Lj6rOJjAOgABEmwW5bjNEDbUAW4FwC8BbFzqLJatQAA9N7CLiiYl5QNY0DUC4GtvFQwgQIiwhUNEowAFIAMo8ieiKFTEAhGCAWJm3ORoIGAJqkX+wjCKM3sW6M6gAHoW5oABUFwW5M3vRJbAAkm7TG7hb6NOtq4JAFgQEQPL52bevbS5QmGYdN53nAD7Pm+H66Rehmy9NonO7w0yLiu21pY962zV5w2EdQxF+cVlGYDR9FC+fYWASZN1cXd8J2wlc9f14e8D7iSPsAlcBRsb9RfmAjel4RoEz+gLc60MoFgO3vTaBiMFZtWeqzDBbN-5BmPng8BXNIEELAXzQmE1yo2GpqA6BaDyGYOshuM+9DAzs2IZ4IhXDdq43YXhWBeV4FFTOjQqWKCrpvwih-dBXDmpIzWjggRbN2GaHEpwwh7CmZKxhngw6vlSJ30pgZch29ooYJ-rZP+7DAELhUdwhxO0IFfSYbzS+R0RH-RJkLEW5MtImOQW4mW0i6p02CYGKxKNdG4OIZo4hPDiF8OlvIoaQjPH82Kj44WZMxYBIltNSRzFQkLQahE7+ijHrM3Rqk+JeDEl4OSUU5SHjfqiMFjk0WYN8l6Ulik1JjCnEVKwdEtGsS8GTjweolcdTMaNJcfw-RHjDEBSChVaIKDzHkKiYlcZ+COjqNhBHEgUcY5xwTinNOGcshZxzqMYewox4Tx1mbC47A2AcEuenTO0Rs6521gXC4QA) using the same algorithm courtesy of [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)

Comment: You should make explicit that you are not trying to "group by `AdminLevel`", although for the data as given this happens naturally.

Comment: @jcalz sure, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: I was working on this also and I think [my solution](https://tsplay.dev/kNr95w) is the same algorithm as yours (so I won't post it)

Comment: @jcalz thanks, I hope you won't mind adding the solution to the answer. Also, how do you make a short link to the TS playground?

Comment: Yeah, it's fine.  The Playground has a Link Shortener plug-in [img](https://i.imgur.com/eLOptLo.png).